# Is it best practice to put the request parameters into other variables?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have a Java servlet running on Apache Tomcat 9. The servlet uses `request.getParameter()` to grab the URL parameters being send to it.

I use the parameters many times in the code to handle them properly, as there are multiple conditions. For this reason, since typing `request.getParameter("paramName")` every time is too long, I put them in variables at the start, like so:

```
String deviceNum = request.getParameter("deviceNum"); 
String tempI = request.getParameter("tempI");
String assetNum = request.getParameter("assetNum");
```

And so on, making the overall code shorter and easier to understand.

However, that got me wondering if that is, in fact, the best practice for this situation. After all, the values are already in the `request`, so puting them in other variables would technically mean duplicating them.

What's the best practice for this situation: using `request.getParameter()` or puting the parameters in variables? Does it alter the reading speed? Or is it irrelevant?

Comment: Of course it's best practice. Repeating the same code over and over again, and risking to make a typo in the parameter name every time, would be bad practice (violates the DRY principle). Being forced to change it in several places if you decide to change the parameter name is also a potential source of bugs.

Comment: Do you know `getParameters()`'s implementation? It might be possible, that repeated calls get different results, or just take too long to execute...

Comment: Who writes a servlet in 2017? :)

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Why, what do you write instead of? EG for dynamic file downloading?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar, it is a good instrument for learners to understand how things work on java backend side (1); servlets give you fine-grained control, more comprehensive than for example Spring does (2)

Comment: UsagiMiyamoto I don't know what EG is in your comment. AndrewTobilko, well by that argument, you should start by implementing a web container as it gives you even more insight on how things work. "I want to reinvent the wheel because it'll give me controls that I don't need or understand" is a good way to work if you're paid by the hour. For the rest of us, there's JAX-RS and Spring and Play and half-dozen other frameworks.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar, EG = for example, I believe :) No, it rather sounds like "I don't want to reinvent the wheel, but I am gonna go down to a lower API to satisfy my needs which can't be fulfilled on the level of these frameworks"

Comment: servlet in 2017 is "must know", but (only) as background to use  framework. I dont agree with simplification "low level = better perfomant"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I think using local variables is better. You don't know the implementation of getParameter, so if the URL-encoding and other stuff happens every time you call that method, calling it once and keeping the result in a variable can save time and resources.

It's also more readable if the parameter name is in some form abbreviated and you pass it to a variable more self-explanatory (e.g. `tempIndex` instead of `tempI` in your particular example with some artistic license on my side concernding the meaning of it ;-). Also, the source gets more compact if you use multiple of these values in a single line. Instead of

```
doSomething(request.getParameter("param1"), request.getParameter("param2"), request.getParameter("param3"), request.getParameter("param4"), request.getParameter("param5"));
```

that most likely will produce a horizontal scrollbar, you can write

```
doSomething(param1, param2, param3, param4, param5);
```

nicely fitting into most source editor panels without the need of scrolling making it a hell of a lot more easy to follow the codes two weeks after you wrote it and you try to figure out what you were thinking back then.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually best practice as you can just refer to the variable every time you need to without the request.getParamater. If you use a framework like struts or something else, it can put it automatically into a variable.

Answer (score 1):

You have chosen a good way to go. Define well-named local variables if they are used in several places.

Also, I would recommend grouping request parameters into objects to continue work with them on a more abstract level. You are not going to pass a bunch of parameters through all the process.

The pattern could be following:

```
String param1 = request.getParameter("param1");
String param2 = request.getParameter("param2");

RequestObject obj1 = RequestObjectBuilder.of(param1).and(param2).build();
// we are no longer working with raw parameters
```

> ... so puting them in other variables would technically mean duplicating them.

You are making a reference to some data after you have found out where it is stored. That is not a copy - don't sweat it.

Comment: agree, grouping parameters to high-level is good direction. Many patterns exist (and almost all have oposition :) ). For example DTO, Data Transfer Obect. Personally I preffer abstraction near to "business code" or "logical objects" and far from "raw http requests"

Comment: I never thought about grouping request parameters into objects, but now I realize how helpfull it can be. I will try this, too.

Comment: @Ernani, have you read "Clean code" by Robert Martin? It is a good book, I would recommend